# Nancy, module not loaded

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm fairly new to [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/). What I'm trying to achieve, is to create a base class `NancyBaseModule` which inherits from the `NancyModule` class. This class is supposed to be responsible for "common stuff". I want to do it like this instead of hiding this sort of features in extension methods or static methods.

The problem I'm facing is that, by adding functionality to this base class, for registering a simple `GET` method, the `Func` of this registered method will never be called when tried accessed in an web-browser for instance. In fact the constructor of the class is never called, which make me thinking that I need to register at least on HTTP-method in the constructor. As you can see if I add the "dummy" path, it will all work.

This is how my Base class looks like:

```
public abstract class NancyBaseModule : NancyModule
{
        public NancyBaseModule(string prefix) : base(prefix)
        {
            //Get("/dummy", p =>
            //{
            //    return "Nothing interesting here, Cowboy.";
            //});

            var configurator = new NancyEndpointConfigurator()
            {
                RegisterWithReturnValue = (path, action) =>
                {
                    Get(path, action);
                }
            };

            RegisterEndpoints(configurator);
        }

        public abstract void RegisterEndpoints(INancyEndpointConfigurator configurator);
    }
```

And my derived class:

```
  public class AckService : NancyBaseModule
    {
        public AckService() : base("AckService")
        {
        }

        public override void RegisterEndpoints(INancyEndpointConfigurator configurator)
        {
            configurator.WithReturnValue("/now", p =>
            {
                return $"Greetings. The time is: {DateTime.Now.ToString()}";
            });
        }
    }
```

Due to my lack of knowledge using Nancy, I'm not quite sure if this is the right approach to take in terms of the design thoughts behind the framework. If anyone do understand want I'm trying to achieve, please pint-point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with the normal registrations `Get(path,Func<>)` syntax,I cannot any benefit to the complexity of overriding methods.Also I would not register routes in the `base class` as that can cause route collisions down the road, only common functions should be in your base module.